# Ktor app is not running inside Kotlin Multiplatform Project using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to configure a Kotlin Multiplatform Project with Android and Ktor modules in it. After configuration, running the Ktor app fails with this message:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -javaagent:/home/lenqnr/intellij-idea/lib/idea_rt.jar=44331:/home/lenqnr/intellij-idea/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/icedtea-sound.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/java-atk-wrapper.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jce.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/resources.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/rt.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-server-netty/1.2.2/86f06a652bf2859236835e802cd81dc884a72c61/ktor-server-netty-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-server-host-common/1.2.2/80e62a4dab4e116aeb50e8017838b83836764bf9/ktor-server-host-common-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-server-core/1.2.2/37ba2773c666ff3f9f35a6d5949b8b8c2edd6adf/ktor-server-core-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-http-cio-jvm/1.2.2/22659690f735fa439b4f91b83ef846e3ec7dedf1/ktor-http-cio-jvm-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-http-jvm/1.2.2/1381ef340b58a3287f1da884b9db7280466c67ff/ktor-http-jvm-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-network/1.2.2/e8b2d5f46acfc25d7e893dde14f8da41ab28b7fd/ktor-network-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-utils-jvm/1.2.2/7c51add50945d74c07926e11acd33b66295903c8/ktor-utils-jvm-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8/1.3.40/2d1d0a2f27fd060787075c69113846803fc27734/kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.3.40.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.1/706a8b8206ead3683ec639dd270d11fd948fbb0e/logback-classic-1.2.1.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.3.40/2995de8f68444ad47f29e7b59962ac31e6301d7e/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.40.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-io-jvm/0.1.10/ec98e487d8c710126001c4f3086e4a0b9c0d3179/kotlinx-coroutines-io-jvm-0.1.10.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-io-jvm/0.1.10/74f179ae134d78ad360770801807c7078e71885/kotlinx-io-jvm-0.1.10.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/1.2.2/71653b85af2fe6baeb5314c2863dffe7aac8068a/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core/1.2.2/6ff48bdfc38a8c22e3fc37605b6a6afaed3b6dbd/kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.40/f2f8357e000fd80d8d799110f012b86fd4637386/kotlin-reflect-1.3.40.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.40/b8a521c687329303778548e2f09b0ba5b2665236/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.40.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/atomicfu/0.12.9/5cee16643956d76c52c7ef345448b0990b6e1e04/atomicfu-0.12.9.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/da76ca59f6a57ee3102f8f9bd9cee742973efa8a/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.typesafe/config/1.3.1/2cf7a6cc79732e3bdf1647d7404279900ca63eb0/config-1.3.1.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http2/4.1.36.Final/ed198d8a5283910b0c062a50dd28ef4688dcb2a5/netty-codec-http2-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.eclipse.jetty.alpn/alpn-api/1.1.3.v20160715/a1bf3a937f91b4c953acd13e8c9552347adc2198/alpn-api-1.1.3.v20160715.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.36.Final/a2c6883a0f2e0adc15e6d764ced0ef044e2311c7/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-epoll/4.1.36.Final/5eb8b3ad0a99a16e5ae492da27544b1143e00606/netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/1.2.1/378913dfc3c6c71e7e2a2853eff2c3e8ac27599/logback-core-1.2.1.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-io/0.1.10/798b764e7f9396e63eb263a83c0385686d69f3e0/kotlinx-coroutines-io-0.1.10.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-io/0.1.10/c407b4bf931379824cf002f110df028cfe18c87c/kotlinx-io-0.1.10.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common/1.2.2/8b54928fbb813408684911eb27d6afeb23c92a4b/kotlinx-coroutines-core-common-1.2.2.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.3.40/ff8f3da514fc2877d1303d55e22d6da8156c29fb/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.3.40.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains/annotations/13.0/919f0dfe192fb4e063e7dacadee7f8bb9a2672a9/annotations-13.0.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlinx/atomicfu-common/0.12.9/ba80bc10a440ea504b5cebd262becf9870e309c3/atomicfu-common-0.12.9.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec-http/4.1.36.Final/62b73d439dbddf3c0dde092b048580139695ab46/netty-codec-http-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-handler/4.1.36.Final/1c38a5920a10c01b1cce4cdc964447ec76abf1b5/netty-handler-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-codec/4.1.36.Final/8462116d327bb3d1ec24258071f2e7345a73dbfc/netty-codec-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport-native-unix-common/4.1.36.Final/d95d7033f400f9472db9da7834c443b96cd4bab0/netty-transport-native-unix-common-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-transport/4.1.36.Final/8546e6be47be587acab86bbd106ca023678f07d9/netty-transport-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-buffer/4.1.36.Final/7f2db0921dd57df4db076229830ab09bba713aeb/netty-buffer-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-resolver/4.1.36.Final/e4d243fbf4e6837fa294f892bf97149e18129100/netty-resolver-4.1.36.Final.jar:/home/lenqnr/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.netty/netty-common/4.1.36.Final/f6f38fde652a70ea579897edc80e52353e487ae6/netty-common-4.1.36.Final.jar ApplicationKt
Error: Could not find or load main class ApplicationKt

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I noticed the module's output path is not included in the `-classpath` option. How should I fix it?

Here's what I did:

1. Create new Gradle project with no additional libraries and frameworks using IntelliJ IDEA
2. Add new Android module
3. Add new Multiplatform module
4. Add new Ktor module
5. Define main method as shown in the [Ktor quick start](https://ktor.io/quickstart/index.html)

If you follow these steps, then I'm pretty sure you'll face the same problem. I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04 just in case.

project structure:

```
hello
├── android
├── common
├── server
│   ├── resources
│   └── src
│       └── Application.kt
├── build.gradle
└── settings.gradle
```

settings.gradle in root project:

```
include ':android', ':common', ':server'
```

build.gradle in root project:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.40")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @lenqnr It sounds like a issue with the project's configuration. But its hard to know what without more information. And the best way to provide that information in a situation like this it to attach a _"Minimal Reproducible Example"_ (sometimes called a _minimal working example_) to your question. See this help topic for information about  creating one: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example If your actual project is small enough and does not contain any proprietary or copyrighted material, you can attach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a bug, not just a problem. I found a temporary workaround from [JetBrains issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-24463#focus=streamItem-27-2874119.0-0).

In IntelliJ IDEA, Go to "Settings / Build, Execution, Deployment / Build Tools / Gradle / Runner" and check the "Delegate IDE build/run actions to Gradle" option as true and it'll work correctly.